# The grouping in the sql I'm having a problem with

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, group-by

I'm moving a project from MySQL to MSSQL. And since I have a non-standard use of grouping on the Mssql side, I can't bring up the correct data. I need a suggestion.

```
SELECT Count(*) AS stok_adet, s.*, m.*,d.*
FROM stok AS s 
CROSS JOIN mermer_cins AS m 
JOIN stok_durum AS d 
ON s.stok_durum_id = d.stok_durum_id 
WHERE  m.mermer_cins_id = '5' 
AND s.blok_no = 'M6320' 
GROUP BY s.bundle_no, 
s.boy, 
s.yukseklik, 
s.hatali 
ORDER BY s.blok_no ASC, 
s.bundle_no ASC, 
s.stok_tarih DESC
```

Mysql result ss: https://i.ibb.co/ssknfwM/mysql.png

---

I tried two different methods on the Mssql side.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as stok_adet,
       s.bundle_no, s.boy, s.yukseklik, s.hatali
FROM stok s CROSS JOIN
     mermer_cins m JOIN
     stok_durum d
     ON s.stok_durum_id = d.stok_durum_id
WHERE m.mermer_cins_id = '5' AND s.blok_no = 'M6320'
GROUP BY s.bundle_no, s.boy, s.yukseklik, s.hatali;
```

Mssql first result ss: https://i.ibb.co/d5wxcD7/mssql-first.png

```
SELECT s.*, m.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM stok_durum d
        WHERE s.stok_durum_id = d.stok_durum_id
       ) as stok_adet
FROM stok s CROSS JOIN
     mermer_cins m
WHERE m.mermer_cins_id='5' AND s.blok_no='M6320'
ORDER BY s.blok_no ASC, s.bundle_no ASC, s.stok_tarih DESC
```

Mssql second result ss: https://i.ibb.co/cY2cvMS/mssql-second.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet another alternative:

```
SELECT sm.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM stok_durum d
        WHERE sm.stok_durum_id = sm.stok_durum_id
       ) as stok_adet
FROM (SELECT s.*, m.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.bundle_no, s.boy, s.yukseklik, s.hatali 
                                ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM stok s CROSS JOIN 
           mermer_cins m 
      WHERE  m.mermer_cins_id = '5' AND s.blok_no = 'M6320' 
     ) sm
WHERE sequm = 1 
ORDER BY sm.blok_no ASC, sm.bundle_no ASC, sm.stok_tarih DESC
```

The subquery uses window functions to choose an arbitrary matching row.

Comment: @KasimŞEN . . . The table aliases were all messed up.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, thanks to you I have overcome a big problem.  

The 'stok_adet' field displays the wrong data. How can we overcome this?

My current screenshots are as follows

Mssql side => https://i.ibb.co/tsmdCss/mssql-stok-adet-count-problem.png
Mysql side => https://i.ibb.co/z4bhxqr/mysql-last-query.png

Comment: @KasimŞEN . . . I think this answers the question you asked.  If you have a new question, ask it as a *new* question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Okay, Gordon. Thank you again for everything. 